# trying to get property of non object, laravel 5?

Tags: php, laravel-5

Here, I retrieve two tables to be displayed on one view page. The images are in the users table. When I clicked the profile tab, it displayed an error message:

```
Trying to get property of non-object.
```

What is wrong with my codes referring to the error message?

upload.blade.php

```
<div id="templatemo_sidebar">
<tr>
    <div id="login">logged in as :</div>
</tr>
@foreach($users as $users)
<div id="img">
    <img src="{!! '/profiles/'.$users->filePath !!}">{{$users->filePath}}
</div>
@endforeach
    {!! Form::open(['action'=>'ProfileController@store', 'files'=>true]) !!}
    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('image', 'Choose an image') !!}
        {!! Form::file('image') !!}
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::submit('Save', array( 'class'=>'btn btn-danger form-control' )) !!}
    </div>

    {!! Form::close() !!}
@foreach($profiles as $profile)
    <div id="profile_sidebar">
        <tr>
            <td>{{$profile->student_name}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>{{$profile->student_id}}</td>
        </tr><br>
        <tr>
            <td>{{$profile->student_ic}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr><br>
            <td><mark>Status : {{$profile->status}}</mark></td>
        </tr>

        @endforeach

    </div>
```

ProfileController.php

```
  public function store(Request $request)
{
    $users = Auth::user();
    if($request->hasFile('image')) {
        $file = Input::file('image');
        //getting timestamp
        //$timestamp = str_replace([' ', ':'], '-', Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString());
        //$name = $timestamp. '-' .$file->getClientOriginalName();
        $name=$file->getClientOriginalName();
        $users->filePath = $name;

        $file->move(public_path().'/profiles/', $name);
    }
    $users->save();
    $users = Auth::user();
    $users = Profile::where('student_id', $users->student_id)->get();
    $profiles = Profile::all();
    return view('profile', compact('users', 'profiles'));
}
```

}

Profile.php

```
class Profile extends Model
  {
protected $table='profiles';
protected $fillable = ['student_id','student_name', 'program','faculty'];


public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('users');
}
public function setFirstNameAttribute($value) {
    $this->attributes['faculty'] = ucfirst($value);
}
public function setLastNameAttribute($value) {
    $this->attributes['program'] = ucfirst($value);
}
public function profilePicture(){
    return $this->belongsTo('User', 'student_id');
}
```

}

Comment: Which line in your code is the error displayed for?

Comment: Can you include your `Profile` model class definition?

Comment: i had added my Profile model above. the error occurs when i call filePath on table users instead of profile with message 'trying to get property of non-object'.

Comment: no. i dont use any code for getting error  message...

Answer (score 2):

In your first foreach you have to use a different variable for iterating through the users collection, like this:

```
@foreach($users as $user)
```

Comment: that's the main cause of getting error; trying to get property of non-object.